# How to target another controller from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm have a payment method on my nodejs app, on the side i have a route to delete an user which should to remove him from my payment gateway too. 
SO i have now two routes :  (DELETE /user/:id) and (DELETE /payment/user/:id) this last is to delete the user subscription from my payment gateway.

Question : 
Is it possible from node to call the controller who manage subscription delete knowing that it accepts only request object (express) ?

```
/*
* Remove subscription
* File ./controllers/payement/subscription.ts
*/
const unsubscribe = (req:express.Request, res:express.Response) {
   // ... code to unsubscribe user
}
/*
* Remove user 
* File ./controllers/user.js
*/
const removeUser = (req:express.Request, res:express.Response) {
    // HERE I WANT TO CALL THE CONTROLLER ABOVE
}
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: you can do this but its not a good practice. The best place to solve this problem is the `Models` where you would apply `Transactions` to make sure that both records are removed

Comment: Hi, thank you, could you explain more please ?

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have this `User` model:

```
const User = Model({
   name: String,
   email: String,
   isDeleted: false
})
```

and `Subscription` model:

```
const Subscription = Model({
   userId: 'User',  // references User model above
   amount: Number
})
```

Now when you delete a user & hence related subscription record, this is how you would do in User model:

```
Route.delete('/user/:id', function(req, res) => {

   let user = null; // for record keeping
   let subscription = null;

   Transaction.start(async () => {
     user = await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
     subscription = await Subscription.findAndDelete({ userId: user.id });
   });

   Transaction.error(() => {
      // resotre user & subscription
   })

})
```

This way you don't have to call controller from other controller & business logic resides in models too.

**Note**: `Transaction` is some dummy library.